# stream live video with ustream in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, streaming, video-streaming

I'm trying to create a simple video gallery that pulls the videos from the recorded shows of a specific Ustream user with ASP.net. I've been doing some research and looking at the API Documentation but can't seem to figure it out all example are in PHP.

Can anyone help me on it..if possible then give me some Code or Blogs links for Asp.net with Ustream.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply! Look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms525208(v=vs.90).aspx 
You can use [ADODB.Stream](http://w3schools.com/ado/ado_ref_stream.asp) in [Classic ASP](http://w3schools.com/asp/default.asp) (works in ASP.Net too) 
Write this in asp:

```
'Set the content type to the specific type that you are sending.

Response.ContentType = "video/mp4"

Const adTypeBinary = 1
Dim strFilePath

strFilePath = server.mappath("stream.mp4")

Set objStream = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
objStream.Open
objStream.Type = adTypeBinary
objStream.LoadFromFile strFilePath

Response.BinaryWrite objStream.Read

objStream.Close
Set objStream = Nothing
```

I think this will help you very much.